# htaccess replace spaces just if URL starts with certain words

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to replace all %20 with + signs but just when the url starts with /some/dir/. For example:

```
http://mydomain.com/some/dir/replace%20here
```

should be redirected to

```
http://mydomain.com/some/dir/replace+here
```

but

```
http://mydomain.com/test/dir/replace%20here
```

should not replace the `%20`

So far I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/some/dir/)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1$2+$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1+$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

but that stills replaces the %20 in /test/dir

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are not correct and moreover `DPI` flag is not supported in all Apache versions. Change your Rewrite rules to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(some/dir)/([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)(.*?)/?$ $1/$2+$3$4 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(some/dir)/([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```